# Parsing HTML page with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Using C# I would like to know how to get the Textbox value (i.e: john) from this sample html script :

```
<TD class=texte width="50%">
<DIV align=right>Name :<B> </B></DIV></TD>
<TD width="50%"><INPUT class=box value=John maxLength=16 size=16 name=user_name> </TD>
<TR vAlign=center>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There are a number of ways to select elements using the agility pack.

Let's assume we have defined our `HtmlDocument` as follows:

```
string html = @"<TD class=texte width=""50%"">
<DIV align=right>Name :<B> </B></DIV></TD>
<TD width=""50%"">
    <INPUT class=box value=John maxLength=16 size=16 name=user_name>
</TD>
<TR vAlign=center>";

HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
```

**1. Simple LINQ**
We could use the [`Descendants()`](https://html-agility-pack.net/descendants) method, passing the name of an element we are in search of:

```
var inputs = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("input");

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input.Attributes["value"].Value);
    // John
}
```

**2. More advanced LINQ**
We could narrow that down by using fancier LINQ:

```
var inputs = from input in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("input")
             where input.Attributes["class"].Value == "box"
             select input;

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input.Attributes["value"].Value);
    // John
}
```

**3. XPath**
Or we could use [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath).

```
string name = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//td/input")
    .Attributes["value"].Value;

Console.WriteLine(name);
//John
```

Comment: LINQ: In the case where the attribute was not there I used the following linq for `where input.Attributes["class"] != null && input.Attributes["class"].Value == "box"`

Answer (score 2):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
XPathNavigator docNav = doc.CreateNavigator();

XPathNavigator node = docNav.SelectSingleNode("//td/input/@value");

if (node != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("result: " + node.Value);
}
```

I wrote this pretty quickly, so you'll want to do some testing with more data.

NOTE: The XPath strings apparently have to be in lower-case.

EDIT: Apparently the beta now supports Linq to Objects directly, so there's probably no need for the converter.