# saving data from an online table/CSV to sql database

Tags: sql, csv, sql-server-2012, sql-job

I am looking into creating an sql database that extracts data from a web page.  The webpage displays the data in either a table or CSV list.

The address of the page is

[Online table/CSV](http://www.bmreports.com/servlet/com.logica.neta.bwp_MarketIndexServlet?displayCsv=false#)

I am not entirely sure how to do this.  I thought maybe to save the page as a text file then import it but I cannot save it.  Am I missing something is there an easy way of doing this?

Apologies I should say that I will use the data in a asp.net application using VB in Visual Studio 2010. The SQL will will be SQL Server 2012.

EDIT - ok so I was informed to run the page in compatibility mode and the CSV will save which I have confirmed.  I therefore need to be able to open the page using a vb console app and perform a save as.  I have tried using the webclient control and I can create a file but it downloads the html of the page as well.  How do I save the contents of the webpage as a csv or text file?

Comment: you want to take data from web page and store in to SQL table , right ??

Comment: Have you ever heard about [Bulk Insert](https://www.google.co.in/#q=bulk+insert+in+sql).?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512562/parsing-html-page-with-htmlagilitypack Try

Comment: yes take the web page data and store it in my table Hussain.  Jenson, Ill take a look.