# Reading String as HTML in c# and obtain Values of Elements by class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a string in c# MVC controller which is HTML.

eg: `<html>...<head>...</head><body>...<div class="someClass">...</div><div class="someClass">...</div><div class="someClass">...</div></body></html>`

Now I want to get all values of elements where Class = someClass and place them in a string array. Is this possible without using string manipulation functions? Currently I am using string manipulation like this

```
string str = above String;
if (str.Contains(@"<div class=""someClass"">"))
{
str = str.Remove(0, str.IndexOf(@"<div class=""someClass"">" + 22));
// add the text in array until </div> and move to next element
```

I am sure there is a way in c#. Can someone please guide me in the right direction.

**Note: That the HTML string is not from File.**

**Note: This is not a Javascript question. Although I would love to use Javascript in Controller for this one.**

Comment: Why are you passing HTML from the controller to the View? You are breaking down all MVC pattern doing that!

Comment: @Fals I am not passing anystring from controller to View. The user is passing me a url from which I am getting the Html using System.Net.HttpWebRequest. Now I need certain values to provide to use from this Html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to parse the HTML string.

Here is an SO question similar to what you are asking:

[Parsing HTML page with HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512562/parsing-html-page-with-htmlagilitypack)

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate HTML in C# using the `HtmlDocument` class.

FROM MSDN [HtmlDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Provides top-level programmatic access to an HTML document hosted by the WebBrowser control.

There's a exemple there. You can access and write html elements using this class.