# Read view source of any web page url and download img in local folder from it in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I want to read a view source of any web page and want to download all images in a folder.

I use below code to read page source:

```
    string address = "http://stackoverflow.com/";  //any web site url

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        txtRead .Text= wc.DownloadString(address);            
    }
```

But in this view source how to get only img src and download images in a local folder.

Thanks,
Hitesh

Answer (score 0):

If you use HtmlAgilityPack you can do something like this

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(yourHtml);
 foreach(HtmlNode imagein doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//img)
 {
    HtmlAttribute src = link["src"];
    CodeToDownloadTheImage(src);
 }
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512562/parsing-html-page-with-htmlagilitypack) for more info.