# IP Logging as 2FA? Problem with 'void' to 'string' and 'Form1.getMyIPAddress()'

Tags: c#, ip, ip-address

I am trying to make an application but for it to work it needs your IP in a text box... So I am trying to use this code to make it work, but it is not working:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myIPAddress.Text = getMyIPAddress();
    }

    private void getMyIPAddress()
    {
        string Address = "";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            Address = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        int first = Address.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
        int last = Address.IndexOf("</body>");
        Address = Address.Substring(first, last - first);
        return Address;
    }
```

Comment: What **specifically** is not working?

Comment: Put the word `static` before `getMyIPAddress`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing HTML page with HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512562/parsing-html-page-with-htmlagilitypack)

Comment: Better use a service that provides webapi than extracting the IP from html. Try this: https://www.ipify.org And you have a two-line working C# example right there to use it...

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/a23oTEi

Comment: private **string** getMyIPAddress()

Comment: @KlausGütter thanks for the help!!! also ZorgoZ ill use the API next time